# What babel plugin should I use for correct work of react-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-dnd

I wanna use `react-dnd` in my project. But I have an error:

```
vm.js:83 Uncaught /my-project-path/node_modules/react-dnd-html5-backend/dist/esm/index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global, Buffer) { return function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import HTML5Backend from './HTML5Backend';
                                                                                                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:265:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:313:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:685:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.react-dnd-html5-backend (http://localhost:1212/dist/renderer.dev.js:29536:18)
```

In compiled code I see this:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global, Buffer) { return function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import HTML5Backend from './HTML5Backend';
import * as NativeTypes from './NativeTypes';
export { getEmptyImage } from './getEmptyImage';
export { NativeTypes };

var createHTML5Backend = function createHTML5Backend(manager, context) {
  return new HTML5Backend(manager, context);
};

export default createHTML5Backend;
}.call(this, exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname); });
```

I understand that it's a some problem with babel but I'm not sure what plugin I should use to solve my problem.

babel:

```
const developmentEnvironments = ['development', 'test'];
const developmentPlugins = [require('react-hot-loader/babel')];
const productionPlugins = [
    require('babel-plugin-dev-expression'),
    require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements'),
    require('@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements'),
    require('babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types'),
];

module.exports = api => {
    const development = api.env(developmentEnvironments);
    return {
        presets: [
            [
                require('@babel/preset-env'),
                {
                    targets: { electron: require('electron/package.json').version },
                    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                    corejs: '3',
                },
            ],
            [require('@babel/preset-react'), { development }],
        ],
        plugins: [
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind'),
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from'),
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators'),
            [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining'), { loose: false }],
            [
                require('@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator'),
                { proposal: 'minimal' },
            ],
            [
                require('@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator'),
                { loose: false },
            ],
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions'),
            [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators'), { legacy: true }],
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent'),
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from'),
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator'),
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions'),
            require('@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'),
            require('@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta'),
            [require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'), { loose: true }],
            require('@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings'),

            ...(development ? developmentPlugins : productionPlugins),
        ],
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your main context provider JavaScript code?
`import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";`

[Full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/lyno0v6ov7)

Answer (score 0):

Since jest is not working with esmodules well, you need to add these configurations in jest.config.js

```
moduleNameMapper : {
        '^react-dnd$': 'react-dnd/dist/cjs',
        '^react-dnd-html5-backend$': 'react-dnd-html5-backend/dist/cjs',
        '^dnd-core$': 'dnd-core/dist/cjs',
}
```